# How to get the second dependency file using Automatic Variables in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to get the nth dependency file from a rule, something similar to $n in bash. I need this because I'd like to feed in individual dependency files as options to the build program.

Here's an example:

```
dep.o: dep.src config1.cfg config2.cfg
    parse -cfg1 $2 -cfg2 $3 -o $@ $<
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
dep.o: dep.src config1.cfg config2.cfg
    @echo the second preq is $(word 2,$^), the third is $(word 3,$^)
```

Comment: References in the (GNU) make manual: [10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for `$^` ("The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them"), and [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) for `$(word n,text)` ("Returns the *n*th word of *text*").