# Can I obtain just the second prerequisite in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the second dependency file using Automatic Variables in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424204/how-to-get-the-second-dependency-file-using-automatic-variables-in-a-makefile)

I am using GNU make, and I'm using automatic variables such at `$<`, `$^` etc.  I know that `$<` is just the first prerequisite, and `$^` is all the prerequisites.  **Is there a way to obtain just the second prerequisite?**

Comment: Could you say a little more about why you need this, or what you're trying to accomplish? You might be able to pick apart `$^` element by element (i.e. treat it as an array), and then grab the second that way.

Comment: @Beta, Yep - this is a duplicate.  I'll vote to close it as such.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Assuming your prerequisites are regular tokens,

```
echo $(word 2,$^)
```

I often find myself giving the first argument a special position, and accessing the remaining prerequisites with

```
echo $(filter-out $<,$^)
```

*Though sometimes with the upper solution you might find repeating elements.

Comment: The filter-out trick is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with, which I feel is a bit of a hack, is to use `echo $^ | cut -f2 -d' '`, à la:

```
output.txt: a.txt b.txt
    cat $< | ./something `echo $^ | cut -f2 -d' '` > $@
```

I'd love to hear a better answer than this. :)

Comment: Here you go: `$(word 2,$^)`